# mapper.readValue not honoring JSON Views

Tags: json, serialization, mapper

I'm using JSONView to hide things from being shown to the API. Everything works if I want to have non-human readable JSON. The problem is, I'm also trying to *prettify* the json to make it look more readable. The second-to-last line in the below method does this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/questions")
public @ResponseBody List<Question> questionListRest() throws IOException { 
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String result = mapper
      .writerWithView(Views.Public.class)
      .writeValueAsString((List<Question>) questionRepository.findAll());
    List<Question> JsonList = mapper.readValue(result, new TypeReference<List<Question>>(){});
    return JsonList;
}
```

However, it initializes 'answer' as null, even though answer should be hidden from the json completely (and it is hidden from the json string before mapper.readValue is called):

`[ {
  "questionId" : 6,
  "questionName" : "Which of the following would you most likely eat?",
  "questionType" : "checkbox",
  "values" : [ "A chainsaw", "A table", "An Apple" ],
  "answers" : null
}, {
  "questionId" : 7,
  "questionName" : "What countries have you visited",
  "questionType" : "checkbox",
  "values" : [ "Finland", "Sweden", "Estonia" ],
  "answers" : null
}, {
  "questionId" : 8,
  "questionName" : "Where did you last feel unconfortable",
  "questionType" : "checkbox",
  "values" : [ "At a bar", "While coding spring", "While eating an unsliced long sub" ],
  "answers" : null
} ]`

Here is my Question class:

```
@Entity
public class Question {

@JsonIgnore
private static AnswerRepository answerRepository; 

@JsonIgnore
private static CategoryRepository categoryRepository;   

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long questionId;
private String questionName;  
private String questionType; //text, radio, checkbox..
private String[] values;


public Question(String questionName, String questionType, Category category, String[] values) {
    super();
    this.questionName = questionName;
    this.questionType = questionType;
    this.category = category;
    this.setValues(values);
}

public Question(String questionName, String questionType, Category category) {
    super();
    this.questionName = questionName;
    this.questionType = questionType;
    this.category = category;
}   

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "categoryid")
@JsonBackReference
private Category category;  

@JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
    return answers;
}

public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
    this.answers = answers;
}

@JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "question")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Answer> answers;   

public Question() {
    super();
}
... getters and setters ...
```

Here is the json before `readValue` is called on it (as in when `result` is logged)

`[{"questionId":6,"questionName":"Which of the following would you most likely eat?","questionType":"checkbox","values":[ "A chainsaw", "A table", "An Apple" ]},{"questionId":7,"questionName":"What countries have you visited","questionType":"checkbox","values":[ "Finland", "Sweden", "Estonia" ]},{"questionId":8,"questionName":"Where did you last feel unconfortable","questionType":"checkbox","values":[ "At a bar", "While coding spring", "While eating an unsliced long sub" ]}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" this by adding `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` to the fields in said null or empty entities. NON_EMPTY hides all values, empty or null, NON_NULL only null values. I probably asked about the wrong thing in the first place.